# How do I add a hyper-link as a content type field?

Tags: views

I want to add a link as a content-type-field, so that it shows up under all the nodes of that content type.

This is because I do not want a link to a taxonomy-term; I want a link to the view I have created for that content type.

Answer (score 1):

For this case you should use one of these (or both) hooks [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) and [hook_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_view/7)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link) field module, but for your use case, yvan's answer is correct and probably more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, an alternative could be creating a copy of node template. Inside your theme directory, create a copy of file node template node.tpl.php, and rename this copy according your Content Type, for example, if machine name of my content type is `my_content_type`, then:

`node-my_content_type.tpl.php`

and adding your custom field in the place that you want, using the machine name of your field, for example, if your field is a cck field, and the machinename is `respective_field_name`, then :

```
  <div class="content clear-block">
    <?php print $content; ?>
  </div>
  <?php echo $node->respective_field_name[0]['value']; //this is the new line near to $content variable ?>
```